# Не запускается скрип по нажатию кнопки

Tags: php

Хочу создать просто кнопку, которая будет выдавать какой -то текст на php. По примеру создала так

```
  <?php
    # Если кнопка нажата
    if( isset( $_POST['my_button'] ) )
    {      
        echo 'Кнопка нажата!';
    }
?>
```

Но ничего не происходит. Подскажите, где ошибка в коде. Html следующий

```
<form  method="POST">
    <input type="button" name="my_button" value="Нажать">
</form>
```

так же пробовала запустить скрипт через файл. Результата нет.

```
<form action="buttons.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="button" name="my_button" value="Нажать">
```

Вот тут вместо `button` надо вставить `submit`, должно получиться так:

```
<input type="submit" name="my_button" value="Нажать">
```

---

`index.php`:

```
<!-- <form action="#" method="POST"> | Либо так-->
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="my_button" value="Нажать">
</form>

<?php
    # Если кнопка нажата
    if( isset( $_POST['my_button'] ) )
    {
        echo 'Кнопка нажата!';
    }
?>
```

Все работает как надо -.-

Comment: Все равно не работает

Comment: @Owl_Livi добавил в ответ -.-

Comment: Совсем не понимаю тогда почему не работает.  Может я не так запускаю?

Comment: @Owl_Livi видимо `PHP` не ваше, я скинул скрипт целиком, не знаю где тут можно накосячить.

Comment: Все, поняла  в чем косяк. Не установила xampp :D